# AWS Appstream 2.0 deploying administrative applicatication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appstream

How do I deploy an administrative privileged application to AWS appstream 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using Active Directory: from the image builder, as administrator, add the "NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE (S-1-5-4)" user to the Administrators group.